# Authentication error with cognito in AWS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

Error in Cognito AWS with PHP

Hello, I have the following error when trying to authenticate with cognito of aws

```
(2/2) CognitoIdentityProviderException
Error executing "AdminInitiateAuth" on "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"__type":"AccessDeniedException","Message":"
```

The code I run is the following

```
$this->client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient([
      'version' => '2016-04-18',
      'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ]);
    $result = $this->client->adminInitiateAuth([
        'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
        'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
        'UserPoolId' => $this->userpool_id,
        'AuthParameters' => [
            'USERNAME' => 'xxxx',
            'PASSWORD' => 'xxxxxx',
        ],
    ]);
```

I'm reviewing but I see everything fine.

**upgrade**
In javascript I have the following function

```
   function AccionLogin(){
var poolData = { 
                UserPoolId : 'xxxx',
                ClientId : 'xxxx'
};
        var userName = "xxxxxx";
        var userPassword = "xxxxx";

        //crear objeto
        var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

        // Sign in
        var userData = { 
            Username : userName,
            Pool : userPool
        };
        cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
        var authenticationData = {
            Username : userName,
            Password : userPassword,
        };
        var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {
                FormPortal(cognitoUser);
            },
            onFailure: function(err) {
                alert(err);
            },
            mfaRequired: function(codeDeliveryDetails) {
                var verificationCode = prompt('Ingrese su codigo de verification:' ,'');
                cognitoUser.sendMFACode(verificationCode, this);
            }
        });
    }
```

Which works correctly and using the same clientID and pollId as in PHP
I'm basically trying to do the same thing from javascript but in php

Comment: Does the role associated with those credentials have permissions to access cognito?

Comment: @Milk Yes, friend the ClientId and the UserPoolId is using with cognito with javascript and the same user authenticates correctly